# Self host kibana 5.1.1 keeps getting request timeout while connecting to AWS Elasticsearch 5.1

Tags: kibana-5

We are testing AWS elasticsearch service 5.1 with selfhost kibana 5.1. 
We keep getting elasticsearch plugin request timeout error also the endpoint is correctly configured in kibana.yml.

IAM policy is correctly configured since logstash servers are fine with elasticsearch.

Anyone ran into the same situation? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify the port even if it's port 80. 
For example
http://your-es-id.ap-northeast-1.es.amazonaws.com:80